# Reusable Vue.js Ajax method. Passing Vue data array name as argument. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have spent the last 9 hours learning a little bit of Vue.js

The following code is my attempt at using Vue.js with JQuery Ajax.

I am having a challenge trying to find out how to get the last argument to work. It seems that if I pass the name of an array that is expected to already exist in vue `data: {...`, nothing happens. It's just empty.

**Update:** I have correct the COORS issue. Console logs work.

Here's the **json file structure**:

```
{
  "status": "DB_SUCCESS",
  "users":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"John",
      "email":"johnk@yopemail.com",
      "phone":"121323232"
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Kelly",
      "email":"kellyk@yopemail.com",
      "phone":"121212122"
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"Ryan",
      "email":"ryank@yopemail.com",
      "phone":"22222212"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The code:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- META TAGS -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS v4.3.1 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONT CSS - Roboto Mono -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100,300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONT CSS - Material Icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- FLATPICKR CSS v4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
    <!-- JQUERY    JS v3.4.1 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- VUE JS v2.6 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="vue.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- PARENT CONTAINER -->
    <div class="container bg-light" id="app" style="min-height: 400px;">
      <!-- FORM -->
      <form class="bg-secondary" style="min-height: 350px;">
        <!-- HEADING -->
        <h2 v-if="titleVisible == true">{{ title }}</h2>
        <!-- FORM-ROW -->
        <div class="form-row mb-3">
          <!-- ROW > COLUMN -->
          <div class="col">
            <!-- BUTTON GET USERS -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" v-on:click="ajaxGetUsers([ {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'} ], 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/10hzkz')">Get Users</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FORM-ROW -->
        <div class="form-row">
          <!-- ROW > COLUMN -->
          <div class="col">
            <!-- LIST-GROUP -->
            <ul class="list-group">
              <!-- LIST-GROUP-ITEM -->
              <li class="list-group-item" v-for="user in arrUsers"> Id: {{ user.id }} - Name: {{ user.name }} - Email: {{ user.email }} - Phone: {{ user.phone }}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>

      // VUE APP INSTANCE
      var App = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          title: 'App 1.0',
          titleVisible: true,
          arrUsers: [] // initialize empty array
        },

        methods: {


          ajaxGetUsers: function ( jsDataArray  = null, jsonEndPoint = null) {
            
            // VALIDATE ARGS
            if(Array.isArray(jsDataArray) === false || jsonEndPoint === null) {
              // DEBUG
              console.error("(i) - AJAX FUNCTION PARAMETERS INCORRECT.");

              return false;
            };

            // CREATE A CLOSURE TO ACCESS COMPONENT IN AJAX "DONE" CALLBACK BELOW
            var self = this;

            // SERIALIZE ARRAY OF OBJECTS
            // let jsDataArray = $("#form1").serializeArray();

            // CUSTOM ARRAY OF OBJECTS
            // let jsDataArray = [
            //   {
            //     key1: 'value1',
            //     key2: 'value2',
            //   }
            // ];

            // DEBUG
            console.info("(i) - JS ARRAY   : POST DATA: ", jsDataArray);
            // JSON.STRINGIFY
            let jsonDataArray = JSON.stringify(jsDataArray);
            // DEBUG
            console.info("(i) - JSON ARRAY : POST DATA: ", jsonDataArray);

            // DEBUG
            console.warn("AJAX request started.");

            // AJAX REQUEST (SELECT - SINGLE RECORD)
            $.ajax(

              {
                url:         jsonEndPoint,
                method:      "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:    "text",
                data:        jsonDataArray,
                timeout:     5000,
              }

              //  (!) - AJAX EVENT: BEFORE-SEND
            ).then(function (data) {

                // DO Something...

                // DEBUG
                console.info("(x) - AJAX EVENT : BEFORE-SEND finished.");

                // RETURN data
                return data;
              }

              //  (!) - AJAX EVENT: DONE
            ).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                // VALIDATE data
                if (data != null) {

                  // JSON.PARSE API END-POINT RESPONSE DATA
                  let jsObject = JSON.parse(data);

                  // DEBUG
                  // console.log("JS OBJECT: ", data);

                  // SERVER RESPONSE STATUS
                  let serverResponse = jsObject;

                  // console.log('here: ', $data.vueDestArray);
                  // *** UPDATE VUE ARRAY arrUsers ***
                  // Update a Template data object property.
                  // self.arrUsers = serverResponse[jsonTargetNode];
                  
                  self.arrUsers = serverResponse.users;

                  // WE USE serverResponse[jsonTargetNode] INSTEAD OF serverResponse.jsonTargetNode 
                  // BECAUSE jsonTargetNode IS AN ARGUMENT VARIABLE OF OUR ajaxGetUsers METHOD.
                  // IT CANNOT BE ACCESSED VIA DOT NOTATION.

                  // DEBUG
                  // console.info("(x) - AJAX EVENT :        DONE finished.", serverResponse[jsonTargetNode]);
                  
                  // DEBUG
                  console.info("(x) - AJAX EVENT :        DONE finished.", serverResponse.users);

                  // MYSQL - CONNECTION SUCCESS
                  if (serverResponse.status == "DB_SUCCESS") {
                    // DEBUG
                    console.info(" |->  SERVER RESPONSE: ", serverResponse.status);
                  }

                  // MYSQL - CONNECTION ERROR
                  if (serverResponse.status == "DB_ERROR") {
                    // DEBUG
                    console.error(" |->  SERVER RESPONSE: ", serverResponse.status);
                  }

                  // [additional serverResponse conditions go here...]

                }

              }

              // AJAX FAIL
            ).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // DEBUG
                console.error("(x) - AJAX EVENT : FAIL fired.", errorThrown);
              }

              // AJAX ALWAYS
            ).always(function () {
              // DEBUG
              console.info("(x) - AJAX EVENT :      ALWAYS finished.");
              // DEBUG
              console.warn("AJAX request finished.");
            });

          } // end ajaxGetUsers : function

        }, // end vue methods

        beforeCreate: function() {
          // 1. beforeCreate: Called synchronously after the instance has just been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup.
          
          // DO Something...
          this.title = 'Loading app... beforeCreate';
          console.info('Loading app... beforeCreate');

        },

        created: function() {
          // 2. created: Called synchronously after the instance is created. At this stage, the instance has finished processing the options which
          // means the following have been set up: data observation, computed properties, methods, watch/event callbacks. However, the mounting 
          // phase has not been started, and the $el property will not be available yet.
          
          // DO Something...
          this.title = 'Loading app... created';
          console.info('Loading app... created');

          this.ajaxGetUsers([ {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'} ], 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/10hzkz');

        },

        beforeMount: function() {
          // 3. beforeMount: Called right before the mounting begins: the render function is about to be called for the first time.
          
          // DO Something...
          this.title = 'Loading app... beforeMount';
          console.info('Loading app... beforeMount');

        },

        mounted: function() {
          // 4. mounted: Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el.
          
          // DO Something...
          this.title = 'Loading app... mounted';
          console.info('Loading app... mounted');

          // this.ajaxGetUsers([ {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'} ], './jsonEndPoint.php');

        },

        beforeUpdate: function() {
          // 5. beforeUpdate: Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el.
          
          // DO Something...
          this.title = 'Loading app... beforeUpdate';
          console.info('Loading app... beforeUpdate');

        },

        updated: function() {
          // 6. updated: Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el.
          
          // DO Something...
          // this.title = 'Loading app...updated';

        }

      }); // end Vue APP
      
    </script>  
    <!-- JQUERY    JS v3.4.1 -->
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- POPPER    JS v1.14.7 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS v4.3.1 -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you have to declare your data as function, but without seeing the actual final code it is hard to predict.

Please see here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Also, in order to make your AJAX function reusable as you ask in your comment, pass a callback function to your "ajaxGetUsers()" and invoke it in the "done()" method of the AJAX request.

That way you can handle the result in your callback function, making the AJAX function reusable.

Comment: This is the final code. It works but for now, I'm having to place `arrUsers` inside the ajax function instead of passing `arrUsers` as an argument(`vueDataArray`) that impersonates `arrUsers`. I fear that without this part, the ajax function is ultimately, not reusable.

Comment: Pass a callback function to your "ajaxGetUsers()" and invoke it in the "done()" method of the AJAX request. That way you can handle the result in your callback function, making the AJAX function reusable.